# Is it possible to have a property containing generic protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a protocol

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  associatedtype DoSmthValue

  func doSmth(_ value: DoSmthValue) -> String
}
```

I also have another protocol:

```
protocol AnotherProtocol {
  associatedtype T: MyProtocol

  var items: [T] { get set }
}
```

and finally my class where I want to use it:

```
class MyClass: AnotherProtocol {
  typealias T = MyProtocol // this code returns an error

  var items = [T]
}
```

But this code returns me `MyProtocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` which is fair enough. I would like to use it like `typealias T = MyProtocol<String>` which is not allowed in Swift. So is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AnotherProtocol` has an associated value which must be some type that conforms to `MyProtocol`. A protocol cannot conform to protocols, including itself, so that type cannot be `MyProtocol`; it has to be a type *conforming* to `MyProtocol`.

`var items`, then, has to be an array of whatever that type is.

So, let's say you have a type conforming to `MyProtocol` which defines the associated type to be `String`:

```
struct Foo: MyProtocol {
    func doSmth(_ value: String) -> String {
        value
    }
}
```

Then you can define `MyClass` as:

```
class MyClass: AnotherProtocol {
   var items: [Foo]
   init(_ items: [Foo]) { self.items = items }
}
```

---

Of course, if you don't want it to be specific to `Foo`, you can make it generic with respect to any type `T` that conforms to `MyProtocol` *and* has an associated type of `String`:

```
class MyClass<T: MyProtocol>: AnotherProtocol where T.DoSmthValue == String {
    var items: [T]
    init(_ items: [T]) { self.items = items }
}

let myClass = MyClass([Foo(), Foo(), Foo()])
```

Answer (score 2):

New Dev's answer is exactly right about how to fix this, but it's also worth realizing why this set of protocols is requiring something that doesn't make sense.

Let's pretend your MyClass definition were legal. I could then write the following code:

```
for item in items {
    // item is of pseudo-type "MyProtocol"
    // (that's illegal, but we're pretending it's not)
    item.doSmth(... what would go here? ...)
}
```

As written, DoSmthValue could require literally any type, and you'd have to provide it. But you don't know what it is (and you *can't* know what it is). There's no way to make use of this protocol; you can't generate the things it requires. So it's not meaningful for `item` to be of type MyProtocol. You need to go back to thinking about what you want the calling code to look like, and that will tell you what kinds of protocols you need. Starting with the protocols (especially if you're new to this) will typically get you in trouble.